# uWSGI Starup file worker process

Tags: python, process, uwsgi

I am trying to understand a uWSGI startup file. Following is a simple code extract…

```
[uwsgi]
Module = WSGI

Master = true
Process = 5
```

The tutorial indicates 5 process, means 5 worker processes to serve actual requests.

My question is, if there are many visitors on the site, is 5 worker process sufficient to serve actual requests?